# Odoo 8/9/10 API, how to create an invoice from a sale order via XMLRPC

Tags: odoo-8, xml-rpc, odoo-9, odoo-10

I'm developing a ruby application which sends some commands to Odoo via XMLRCP API.
I've been able to create a sale order in this whay

```py
def execute_odoo_command(odoo_model, odoo_command, values)
  @models.execute_kw(ODOO_DB, @uid, ODOO_PASSWORD, odoo_model, odoo_command, values)
end

def create_order_sale
  order_reference = "SO #{@reference_code}_#{@customer_odoo_id}"
  values = {
    currency_id: 1,
    date_order: Date.today.to_s,
    name: order_reference,
    payment_term: 1,
    partner_id: @customer_odoo_id
  }
  order_id = execute_odoo_command('sale.order', 'create', [values])
  create_sale_order_lines(order_id)
  execute_odoo_command('sale.order', 'action_confirm', [order_id])
end
```

Now, I would launch the invoice creation. I have found a way to do it like this

```
execute_odoo_command('account.invoice', 'create', [invoice_values(order_reference)])
```

But, even if the invoice is created, the sale order is stil "open" and I can create another invoice from the Odoo interface clicking on "Create Invoice" button (which is obviously wrong). Is there any way to simulate that action via API?

The debug mode does not show any method in the tooltip.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future googlers. The solution is that I'm using an old API version. the right command call is this one

```
  def create_invoice_from_sale_order(sale_order_id)
    sale_order_to_invoice_data = [sale_order_id, {context: {active_ids: sale_order_id}}]
    @odoo_rpc_client.execute_odoo_command('sale.order', 'action_invoice_create', sale_order_to_invoice_data)
  end
```